# Simulate a StepCounter

Tags: python, class

I have an exercise where I have to develop a class with the name `StepCounter`. When generating an instance of `StepCounter` a date in a form of a string should be handed over to the class.

There has to be a method that should raise the step counter by 1 and a method that should give an output like `"You walked 1000 steps on 08.01.2019"`

To test this I should also write a program that should simulate a random number of steps, but it should be counted after every single step. In the end the text should appear.

So my first idea looks like this:

```
import random as rnd 

class StepCounter:
    date = "08.01.2019"

    def increment_steps(self,counter):
        self.counter = counter
        self.counter += 1

    def to_string(self):
        print("On " + self.date + " I walked " + str(self.counter) + " steps.")


i = 0
random_steps = rnd.randint(1,300)
while i < random_steps:
    count = StepCounter()
    count.increment_steps(i)
    i += 1

count.to_string()
```

But I have the feeling that this is a wrong solution, since I am counting with my while loop instead of the class. Do you have a different approach?

Comment: Your code clearly doesn't meet those requirements. You are always increasing the count by `i + 1`, so only for the first value of `i` are you actually increasing the count by the required single step. Also: the date is a class attribute, it's **not** provided when creating an instance.

Comment: Until you have a demonstrable, known problem, you do not have a Stack Overflow posting.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you employ *incremental programming*: get a small part of the program working, then gradually expand.  Add only a few lines at a time.  At the moment, you have several pieces, apparently none of them tested, and you seem to have lost focus.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know that I can't ask general questions here. I am gonna close the post then. Sorry for the inconvenience I caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. Since this is your homework, I'm not going to write a complete answer here, but I hope I can give you some hints in the right direction.

The while loop isn't the problem here, it's perfectly fine to use a while loop in your test, since your class only allows incrementing by 1, so you **do** need a loop to increment a random number of times. You might want to look into using a `for`loop with `range` though.

Let's look at that loop a little closer.

```
while i < random_steps:
    count = StepCounter()
    count.increment_steps(i)
    i += 1
```

With each iteration of the loop (each time the code in the loop runs), you're creating a new instance of `StepCounter`. A step counter is initialized with a count of 0, so you're constantly creating new step counters, and incrementing them to 1. Initialize your counter outside the loop, and your output should look a lot better.